# What does とし mean in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

What does `とし` mean in the following sentence?

> 若者はオーストラリア人のようになろう**とし**、オーストラリアで育ったので、両親の伝統を無視したりします

Comment: なろうとする means "try to become", なろうとし is the 連用形.

Comment: @dainichi:  [Comments are not for answers](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/q/593/78)

Comment: @istrasci, you're right. Added a very short answer.

Answer (score 2):

なろうとする means "try to become", なろうとし is the 連用形. So basically "trying to become like Australians, ..." or "try to become like Australians, and ..."